# Merge fails sometime in JPA Hibernate but in same transaction PERSIST works

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge, persistence, persist

> I have gone through the detached and attached entity as per my understanding

```
User user=entityManager.find(User.class,1);
```

here user is a attached entity any changes to this will be reflected in database

> And detached entity is Newly created entity which you can use merge instead of persist in a following way@

```
 User userDetached=new User;
 user.setID(1);
 User userattahed=entityManger.merge(userDetached);
 userattahed.setName("cool");
```

Here name will be reflected in database...if i am not wrong

Below is my code where few times (100/10) merge doesn't work where as persist 100% works...

```
            entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
            UsersModel user=entityManager.find(UsersModel.class,getMobile_num());
            TrackModel track=new TracksModel();
            user.setBalance(user.getBalance().add(getAmount()));
            track.setMobile_Num(getMobile_num());
            track.setTransaction_Type(getTransaction_Type());
            track.setAmount(getAmount());
            entityManager.merge(user);//doesn't update few times 
            entityManager.persist(track); //works 100%
            JPAUtil.commit();
```

Comment: why are you merging an entity that is in "managed" state? pointless since updates will be "known about".

Comment: @NeilStockton i do understand what you meant but does it effect anything ??

Comment: It means your call is pointless (just as pointless as comparing with use of persist on a DIFFERENT object). And if you want to DEBUG your problem then you look at the log for whatever is your chosen JPA provider.

Answer (score 0):

This line is a bit strange:

```
user.setBalance(user.getBalance().add(getAmount()));
```

It is the only change you actually do on the user. What does it do? What is the balance, what does add do with it? There is probably no change in some cases at all, so there is nothing to store.

Since it is in the session anyway (it's loaded before), you do not need to call anything to persist it. It will be flushed at the latest on commit.

Also note that the changes are not necessarily flushed to the database when you call persist of merge or anything like this. It may flush on commit. So always run the transaction to its end before you decide what had been flushed.

Comment: thanks for reply...Balance attribute is a BigDecimal datatype....where i need to add the Amount(getAmount) to user current Balance so i am doing like this  user.setBalance(user.getBalance().add(getAmount()));

Comment: It still may be that Amount is zero? How do you determine whether "it works" or not?

Comment: you see track.setAmount(getAmount()); line which get PERSIST in DB...telling that the last transaction AMOUNT was this track.getAmount

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue where consequent persist and merge fail; here is example of code that was breaking:

```
public MyType persistMyType(MyType myType) {
        MyType merge = em.merge(myType);
        em.persist(merge);
        return merge;
}
```

Once I have removed merge, I haven't had that problem any longer.

PS: MyType was a child of the MyParent where it was annotated like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="myParent", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

I am glad I found work-around, I still don't know what went wrong. I tend to believe that issue is related with dirty objects. SQL logging shows plenty SELECTs that happen before persisting, which can give you a clue what's hibernate doing.